# JWT and requesting application consent; also, manual vs SDK

Tags: php, sdk, docusignapi

Windows 2012, PHP 7.4.

I having a really hard time getting this going, and the more I fuss with it the more confused and frustrated I become. I'm already behind on the project, so I need to start asking questions.

Working server-side: everything is handled by our application: click a button, it does all the processing without any further interact.

The task is "simple": send a PDF out for remote signing. Signature tabs are already placed in the PDF, all I have to do is SEND.

Question #1: Getting the JWT token and requesting application consent is a process, but it only has to be done once per application, right?

Question #2: The SDK seems to be overkill. I've written against REST APIs before and I'm comfortable working in that world. So, SDK vs. manually writing what I need. Advice? And whichever choice is preferred, where do I start?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you server side only, or are you client side, specifically in regards to authorizing the grants? Client side tends to be more involved because of tampering and MitM. Server side tends to have more initial setup but is more straightforward.

Comment: Server-side. Click a button in the interface, our application does all the work behind the scenes.

Comment: This all really depends on the server you are interacting with. We have one install where we gave the 3rd party keys (to sign or verify, can’t remember), and whenever a request for a JWT was made, all previous JWTs were invalidated. That’s usually fine, however our integration tests would then invalidate the production JWTs, so we had to add some logic to regenerate on certain failures.

Comment: For the other question, we went without an SDK, I think we just used Guzzle for transport but we did use [this](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) to generate the payloads properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question #1: Getting the JWT token and requesting application consent is a process, but it only has to be done once per application, right?

Getting consent from the user who will be impersonated by your app is a one time process. Depending on your use case, the "user" could be a "system user" such as finance@example.com or the user could be a specific person.

More on [getting consent](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/oauth-jwt-granting-consent).

The access token that you get back from the JWT grant flow lasts an hour. So you'll need to repeat the JWT call if you need to make another API call after that. Please `do not` create a new JWT grant for each API call! Cache the access token.

> Question #2: The SDK seems to be overkill. I've written against REST APIs before and I'm comfortable working in that world. So, SDK vs. manually writing what I need. Advice? And whichever choice is preferred, where do I start?

Half of the developers who use the DocuSign eSignature REST API call the API directly. So we're happy for you to do that if you prefer.

Create the request object as a PHP associative array, convert it to JSON and then call the API using your favorite HTTPS request library.

If you have a problem doing so, open a new StackOverflow question.